# Javascript Scope and Recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion, scope

When calling this function I am expecting `myStrings` to be `['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']` when in fact I'm seeing `['A', 'B', 'G']`. When the recursive call is made `a[i]` equals `[['C','D'],'E','F']` however the function receives the entire `myArray`. Any ideas?

```
var myArray = ['A','B',[['C','D'],'E','F'],'G'];

var myStrings = [];

function extractStrings(a) {

    for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {

        if(typeof a[i] === 'string') {
            myStrings.push(a[i]);
        } else if (typeof a[i] === 'object') {
            extractStrings[a[i]];
        }
    }
}

extractStrings(myArray);
console.log(myStrings);
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a simple typo:

```
extractStrings[a[i]];
```

Should be:

```
extractStrings(a[i]);
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/SGZtC/)

Comment: Grrr! Time to go to bed. Thanks.